# How does this SQL Left join on itself work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Temp_Test
 (Main_id int,
  Unique_id char(1)  )

insert into Temp_Test(Main_id,Unique_id)
values  (1, 'a'),
        (2, 'b'),
        (3, 'c'),
        (4, 'c')

SELECT   r.Main_Id, r.Unique_ID, x.Main_Id, x.Unique_id
FROM        dbo.Temp_Test r
        LEFT  JOIN dbo.Temp_Test x
                ON r.Unique_ID = x.Unique_ID
                    AND x.Main_Id < r.Main_Id
WHERE       x.Main_Id IS NULL
```

I'm trying to understand how this query works. When running it in steps, it just made me more confused. When it's ran just as

```
   SELECT    r.Main_Id, r.Unique_ID, x.Main_Id, x.Unique_id
    FROM        dbo.Temp_Test r
            LEFT  JOIN dbo.Temp_Test x
                    ON r.Unique_ID = x.Unique_ID
```

the results turn into

```
Main_ID  Unique_ID  Main_id  Unique_id
1          a           1      a
2          b           2      b
3          c           3      c
3          c           4      c
4          c           3      c
4          c           4      c
```

But when ran with the x.main_id < r.main_id filter, we get

```
Main_ID  Unique_ID   Main_id    Unique_id
1          a           NULL      NULL
2          b           NULL      NULL
3          c           NULL      NULL
4          c           3         c
```

What happened to the 4 C 4 C row?

Comment: 4 is not strictly less than (`<`) 4. 4 is less than or equal to (`<=`) 4.

Comment: How is the row omitted entirely?

Comment: Because `4 C` on the left side is already represented in the output.

Answer (score 1):

When you do left join, all the records from the left table will be part of the result. If query finds match from second table, it will show them in result or else will simply print NULL.

In first query, it did find an match with Unique_id's so it gave you results with all possible pairs.

In second query, since there were no records where Main_id was greater in first table (for 1,2,3) it returned NULL for second table.
Whereas, it found Main Id 4 from table at the left to be greater than 3 from table at the right so it displayed the result.
Since Main_id 4 from left table is not greater than the Main_id 4 from the right table, that is not a part of the result.

Comment: Since the 4 from the left table is not greater than 4 from the right table how did it not receive the null values as did the 1 A  1 A; 2 B  2 B and 3 C 3 C records?

Comment: as @welbog said, it already has appeared in the result as 4 C 3 C. So it wont print the NULL value results. Had there been something from the right table it would have given you that in the output.

Comment: I would suggest you to add more columns and rows to see how it works with different filters, so that you can understand it better.